# Display output on new lines? Not all on the same line?

Tags: powershell

I have this script which returns the reboot times of my machine.

Does anyone know how to get the output to return on a new line for each entry tho? Right now, it displays in a single line and cuts off.

```
$rebootTimes = @( get-eventlog system | where-object {$_.eventid -eq 6006} | select-object -ExpandProperty Timegenerated )
$output = "" | Select-Object 'Rebooted at'
$output.'Rebooted at' = $rebootTimes
Write-Output $output
```

I have tried using an array but the same applies!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) with [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2).

Worth noting, [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7.3) replaces [`Get-EventLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1) and should be the cmdlet you should use going forward:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
    Id      = 6006
    LogName = 'System'
} | Where-Object TimeCreated | Select-Object @{ N='Rebooted at'; E={ $_.TimeCreated }}
```